# Shared memory with forked child

Tags: c, linux, fork, shared-memory

I have the following code which is supposed to create a forked process to execute the Collatz conjecture (based on a passed value), and push the integers into shared memory.  When the child process is done, the parent process is supposed to print out the values.  For some reason, my code works sometimes but not others.  From debug statements, I can see the values get pushed in but sometimes the code to print out the values doesn't appear to execute (just some blank lines get printed).  I am using Debian Linux in a virtual box.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main()
{
   const int SIZE = 2048;
   const char *name = "SHARON";
   int  shm_fd;
   void *ptr;
   int count = 1;

   /* Setup shared memory */
   shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
   ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE);
   ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);

   /* Get the starting value */
   int value;
   printf("Enter a positive integer value: ");
   scanf("%d", &value);
   printf("\n");
   if (value < 0)
   {
      printf("ERROR: Integer value must be positive!");
      return 1;
   }

   /* Fork child process */
   pid_t pid;
   pid = fork();

   fork();
   if (pid < 0)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "FORK FAILED\n");
      return 1;
   }
   else if (pid > 0) /*parent process*/
   {
      wait();  /*wait for child to send */
      while (atoi((char *)ptr) != 0)   /*0 is terminate value*/
      {
         printf("%s", (char *)ptr);
         ptr += sizeof(int);
         if (atoi((char *)ptr) != 0)
            printf(", ");
      }

      printf("\n");
      shm_unlink(name);
   }
   else if (pid == 0)   /* child process */
   {
      sprintf(ptr, "%d", value);
      ptr += sizeof(value);

      while (value != 1)
      {
         if (value % 2 == 0)
            value /= 2;
         else
            value = value * 3 + 1;

         sprintf(ptr, "%d", value);
         ptr += sizeof(value);
      }
      sprintf(ptr,"0");   //push a "terminate" value
      ptr += sizeof(value);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps because you are calling `fork` twice in succession?

Comment: Why are you putting a string zero into shared memory but then advancing the size of an integer zero?

Comment: OMG, how did I not see that?  That looks like that was the issue!  I also fixed the pushing 0, like David pointed out.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

There is two fork() call. which will create two child.

```
  pid = fork();

   //fork();
```

Can you try with above.